# custom test report for android connected tests (espresso)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

We have a JUnit test `Rule` for espresso tests that records test results in a `json` file. After test execution the json file is pulled from the device/emulator back to the pc, using `adb shell pull` command.

above solution works only if we run the test using `adb` but not with Gradle.  Gradle uninstalls the apk after running the connected tests, therefore the json file also gets removed from the device.

my question: Is there a way to copy the file before it gets deleted by Gradle?
I was wondering how other report generators tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Pulling most of this idea from [here](https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/how-to-capture-screenshots-for-failed-ui-tests-9927eea6e1e4), but the tl;dr is that you can set up a gradle task to pull the file off of the device.

Real rough idea would be:

```
def pullJsonFromEmulator = task('Pull Json From Emulator', type: Exec) {
    executable "${android.getAdbExe().toString()}"
    args 'pull', 'pathToJson', 'destinationPath'
}

tasks.withType(Test) { task -> 
    task.finalizedBy {
        pullJsonFromEmulator
    }
}
```

The thought process is that you define your custom task to run that will pull the Json off of the emulator and store it somewhere. You can then use gradle's `finalizedBy` functionality to apply this task after all "test" tasks. You can obviously make it more granular, say only tasks with a certain name...

```
tasks.withType(Test) { task -> 
    if (task.name == "jsonTestTask") {
        task.finalizedBy {
            pullJsonFromEmulator
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution is similar to what we are doing currently (using adb pull).  the problem is that gradle uninstall the app and removes all apps data, after executing the `connectedAndroidText` .  So the pull is not going to find anything on the device/emulator to copy.  the article you referenced is using a deprecated feature in android to save screenshots in a public storage. this feature is no longer available in android 10+.

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` was deprecated, but afaik you can just hardcode where you want the images saved, for example, in my project we just ignore that line and use `this.mDefaultScreenshotPath = File("/sdcard/pictures", subdirectory)`. Could you save the json file somewhere not explicitly associated with the app under test (such as `/sdcard/downloads`? Also, would it be possible to save the JSON locally instead of on the emulator?

Comment: i believe in android 11, we cannot write to public folders like (pictures or ...)  easily.  I am trying to find a way to save the report locally instead of emulator but couldn't find any solutions so far.  there seem to be no easy way to do such thing